# Get value of each cell from dynamic table

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

I have dynamic table which is create like this

```
<table id="sort" class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Nazwa kolumny z BD*</th>
                        <th>Długość rekordu*</th>
                        <th>Nazwa kolumny wyświetlana</th>
                        <th>Format*</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="tblsort">
                    @for (var i = 0; i < Model.listOfFormats(Model.field.TemplateName).ColumnNamesDB.Count; i++)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.listOfFormats(Model.field.TemplateName).ColumnNamesDB[i], new { @class = "form-control", })</td>
                            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.listOfFormats(Model.field.TemplateName).LengthColumns[i], new { @class = "form-control" })</td>
                            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.listOfFormats(Model.field.TemplateName).ColumnNamesUser[i], new { @class = "form-control" })</td>
                            <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model.listOfFormats(Model.field.TemplateName).Formats[i], new SelectList(Model.formatFieldValues, "Value", "Text"), Model.listOfFormats(Model.field.TemplateName).Formats[i], new { @class = "form-control" })</td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

How can I get value from each cel in this table? Thanks for help !

edit:

Ok I mean every cell data.

I tried your's solutions but nothing works

here is mine .html which is generate by browser

```
<tbody id="tblsort">
                        <tr>
                            <td name="cos"><input class="form-control" id="ColumnNamesDB_0_" name="ColumnNamesDB[0]" type="text" value="zzzz" /></td>
                            <td><input class="form-control" id="LengthColumns_0_" name="LengthColumns[0]" type="text" value="111" /></td>
                            <td><input class="form-control" id="ColumnNamesUser_0_" name="ColumnNamesUser[0]" type="text" value="zzzzz" /></td>
                            <td><select class="form-control" id="Formats_0_" name="Formats[0]"><option value=""></option>
<option value="DD-MM-YYY">DD-MM-YYY</option>
<option value="DDMMYYY">DDMMYYY</option>
<option value="NRB">NRB</option>
</select></td>
                            </tr>
                    </tbody>
```

When I run this code:

```
 var value = $("#ColumnNamesDB[0]").attr('value');
    var bla = $('.ColumnNamesDB_0_').val();

    alert(bla);
    alert(value);
```

I'm getting "undefined". Whats wrong?

Comment: I have try a lot of things but nothing works I usually get in alert "Undefined" and "Object object"

Comment: your example code does not work because you are trying to select an element with id `ColumnNamesDB[0]` which doesnt exist - just remove `[0]`. see my answer

Comment: Thanks it works var value = $("#ColumnNamesDB_0_").attr('value');

Answer (score 1):

I dont know what you mean by "value", but you can iterate over each `<td>` using jQuery [each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)

```
$(function() {

  var myArray = [];

  $('#tblsort td input').each(function() {
    var input = $(this),
      value = input.attr('value');

    myArray.push(value);
  });
  console.log(myArray);
});
```

Comment: I have edtied my question I mean all cell data in my table

Answer (score 0):

If what you mean is you want to grab ALL the cell's data. So you have to give the "name" attribute to each cell, and grab ALL the data using the name..

```
<td name="example[]"></td>
```

And you can grab it using the language you wanted (Jquery or PHP)..

Comment: You do not have to input a value into the  []  ...

Just use like this


name="ColumnNamesDB[]"


Let me know if it works..

Comment: Ok and now How should i grab it using jquery? because var value11 = $("#ColumnNamesDB[]").val(); doesn't work

Comment: OK, now you use $("input[name=ColumnNamesDB]").val();

Remember, without []... Try it out...

Hope it works~

Comment: I'm getting "undefined" :(

Comment: Are you still struggling with this issue?

"undefined"  means that you do not give any value to the  <td>  tags..

<input type="text" name="columnNames[]" value="1" />
<input type="text" name="columnNames[]" value="2" />
<input type="text" name="columnNames[]" value="3" />

I'm sure you can grab the values.